# what does while ((*s = *t) != ’\0’) mean?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I was reading about pointers in K&R book here

https://hikage.freeshell.org/books/theCprogrammingLanguage.pdf

and then, explaining what strcpy do exactly its written :

```
/* strcpy: copy t to s; pointer version */
void strcpy(char *s, char *t) {
  while ((*s = *t) != ’\0’) {
    s++;
    t++;
  }
}
```

But I couldn't understand the line `while ((*s = *t) != ’\0’)` in which there are 2 of ().

What I learned is using it as : `while( condition )` !

Comment: Hint: read carefully about what the `=` operator does.

Comment: @NateEldredge a=b means puting th value of b in a

Comment: @wadieel: It does one more thing. Have you ever seen a statement like `a = b = 0;`, which assigns 0 to both `a` and `b`? Can you figure out how it does that?

Comment: @JerryCoffin i can figure it intuitionnaly but here in our case we have (a=b)=0

Comment: @wadieel No, you have `(a = b) != c`, which is quite different.  Changing `!=` to `=` would result in an invalid assignment expression (bad left hand side).

Comment: The thing to keep in mind is that an assignment like `a = b` is an expression, whose type and value are the type and new value of `a`.  So it first performs the assignment, then uses the value of the assignment expression in a comparison.

Comment: @TomKarzes thanks for your last comment ! I am understanding things now ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really dense way of writing:

```c
void strcpy(char *s, char *t) {
  while (true) {
    // The condition in the loop in your question
    *s = *t;
    if (*s == '\0)
      break;
    // The body in the loop in your question
    s++;
    t++;
  }
}
```

The shorter (in lines of code) version in the K&R book works because the expression `(*s = *t`), does two things:

1. It assigns to `*s` the value in `*t`.
2. The expression `(*s = *t)` has the value of `*t`.

So we can use that to break out of the loop after assigning `*t` to `*s` if `*t == '\0'`.

Comment: I dont understand the difference between (*s = *t) and *s = *t , is it the same ? so why (*s = *t) has the value of *t ?

Comment: Actually it has the type and new value of `*s`, which is not necessarily the same as `*t`.  In this example they're the same, but if `*s` and `*t` have different types, it isn't.

Comment: @wadieel - the parentheses are necessary because `=` has a lower precedence than `==`, so `*s = *t == '\0'` would be parsed as `*s = (*t == '\0')`, changing the meaning of the expression.

Answer (score 2):

```
while ((*s = *t) != ’\0’)
```

Actually, there is an assignment, followed by a comparison:

1. `*s = *t; // copy the character *t in the string s`
2. Compare the value of this character with `\0`, if equals the loop is finished

In order to reduce the number of lines of code, they put all in 1 line.

Comment: Affectation? Pretty sure that's not what you meant. "Assignment" perhaps?